# Dual form of the least square solution (ridge rigression)

Tags: regression, least-squares, ridge-regression, kernel-trick, linear-algebra

I was reading this [introductory material](https://cml.rhul.ac.uk/publications/files/tr0901.pdf) and on the 5th page, it describes the dual form of the least-square solution (with ridge regression) as $$A(aI + A^\top A)^{-1} = (aI + AA^\top)^{-1}A$$ for a $T\times n$ matrix $A$, identity matrix $I$ and a scalar value $a$. According to the materials, I'm assuming that $T$ is the number of observations and $n$ is the number of predictors.

I couldn't prove the above equality both theoretically and numerically, and it is an important point to move to the next section (about kernel regression), so I'm posting it here seeking your help proving the equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking about the relation above, you can show in general that if $\mathbf A, ~\mathbf B$ are of full ranks, then $$(\mathbb I+\mathbf{AB})^{-
1}\mathbf A=\mathbf A(\mathbb I+\mathbf{BA})^{-1}.$$

To see that, note $\left((\mathbb I+\mathbf{AB})^{-
1}\mathbf A\right) ^{-1}=\mathbf A ^{-1}(\mathbb I+\mathbf{AB})=\mathbf A ^{-1}+\mathbf B=(\mathbb I+\mathbf B\mathbf A) \mathbf A ^{-1}=\left(\mathbf A(\mathbb I+\mathbf{BA})^{-1}\right)^{-1}.$

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant explanation. If we let $A=X^T$ and $B=X$, and $X$ is an $T\times n$ matrix similar to the matrix $A$ described in the question, then this would prove the equality of the equations.